# How can I graph the following: $y=x^2-2x-8$

Tags: polynomials

What is the connection between the y-intercept and the the rule $y=x^2-2x-8$?

Answer (score 3):

The $y$-intercept is the point where the function crosses the $y$-axis. This is simply where $x=0$, thus:
$$y = 0^2-2\cdot0-8 = -8.$$

The $y$-intercept is therefore $(0,-8)$.

In general, for a polynomial $y=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$, the $y$-intercept is $(0,a_0)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2-2x-8=(x-1)^2-9$$

so the minimum point is $P(1/-9)$. Draw the normal parabola with this minimum point.

The roots of the polynomial (interception with the y-axis) are $-2$ and $4$. The 
 minimum is in the middle of these roots. You get the additional points $(-2/0)$ and $(4/0)$.

Because $-2$ and $4$ are roots, the function can also be written as $f(x)=(x+2)(x-4)$